# double free or corruption (!prev) error when push_back to a vector

Tags: c++, c, pointers, boost, vector

I am creating a boost shared pointer from another boost shared ptr pointer and add it to a vector in another class as below:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Parcel> parcel; // this is a variable initialized in the constructor when the class is created.

boost::shared_ptr<Parcel> profitableParcel = parcel;
            devModel->addProfitableParcels(profitableParcel);
```

The function which adds the pointer to the vector in as follow:

```
        void DeveloperModel::addProfitableParcels(boost::shared_ptr<Parcel> profitableParcel)
        {
            {
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock(addParcelLock);
                std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Parcel> > profitableParcels;
                profitableParcels.push_back(profitableParcel);
            }
        }
```

I am getting a SIGABRT: ABORTED error (double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007fffac0d0c00 ***) when trying to add the second element to the vector in int_free (malloc.c) Below is the stack trace:
[image]

Below is another stack trace I am getting for the same. 
[image]

Below is the copy constructor and assignment operator of Parcel.cpp. It seems that somehow before the copy constructor of the Parcel class the "source" variable becomes null.

```
 Parcel::Parcel( const Parcel& source)
{
    this->id = source.id;
    this->tazId = source.tazId;
    this->lot_size = source.lot_size;
    this->gpr = source.gpr;
    this->land_use_type_id = source.land_use_type_id;
    this->owner_name = source.owner_name;
    this->owner_category = source.owner_category;
    this->last_transaction_date = source.last_transaction_date;
    this->last_transaction_type_total = source.last_transaction_type_total;
    this->psm_per_gps = source.psm_per_gps;
}

Parcel& Parcel::operator=( const Parcel& source)
{
    this->id = source.id;
    this->tazId = source.tazId;
    this->lot_size = source.lot_size;
    this->gpr = source.gpr;
    this->land_use_type_id = source.land_use_type_id;
    this->owner_name = source.owner_name;
    this->owner_category = source.owner_category;
    this->last_transaction_date = source.last_transaction_date;
    this->last_transaction_type_total = source.last_transaction_type_total;
    this->psm_per_gps = source.psm_per_gps;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have edited the code to be clear. Thanks.

Comment: @gishara please read the link in Drop's comment. You must post a MCVE.

Comment: Could it be possible, that the error occures in the destructor of Parcel?

Comment: Hi @JojOatXGME, Thanks. I don't do anything in the parcel. The error occurs at the de-allocating as per the stack trace.

Comment: I think that `profitableParcels` is a member of `DeveloperModel`. Could it be that the instance of `DeveloperModel` is not valid?

Comment: Hi @JojOatXGME, thanks for the reply. DeveloperModel instance is valid, I think I found the problem. This is a multi threaded program and I when I changed the mutex from  "boost::mutex::scoped_lock(addParcelLock)" to "addParcelLock.lock()" and unlock after the error was gone.

Comment: @gishara Oh, I haven't seen it. I think you have to use `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` like this: `scoped_lock guard(addParcelLock);`. If you write `scoped_lock(addParcelLock);`, you crate a instance of `scoped_lock` but you doesn't store it anywhere. This mean the object is destroyed and the lock is freed before the rest of the function is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JojOatXGME.